# Changing the name of the downloaded xls file in pivot view odoo

Tags: pivot, odoo, xls

I want to change the name of the xls file that the user can download in Point of Sale module, Stock Pivot view.
on click of the download button in pivot view, Instead of "table.xls" I want it to be for example "03-17-2020.xls"
but I don't know how to change it
i tried looking for any source or example here or in the odoo forum but i can't see any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try To this code in Your controller/ section

```
from collections import deque
import json

from odoo import http
from odoo.http import request
from odoo.tools import ustr
from odoo.tools.misc import xlwt
from datetime import date
from odoo.addons.web.controllers.pivot import TableExporter  # Import the class


    class CustomTableExporter(TableExporter):# Inherit in your custom class

        @http.route('/web/pivot/export_xls', type='http', auth="user")
        def export_xls(self, data, token):
            jdata = json.loads(data)
            nbr_measures = jdata['nbr_measures']
            workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
            worksheet = workbook.add_sheet(jdata['title'])
            header_bold = xlwt.easyxf("font: bold on; pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour gray25;")
            header_plain = xlwt.easyxf("pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour gray25;")
            bold = xlwt.easyxf("font: bold on;")

            # Step 1: writing headers
            headers = jdata['headers']

            # x,y: current coordinates
            # carry: queue containing cell information when a cell has a >= 2 height
            #      and the drawing code needs to add empty cells below
            x, y, carry = 1, 0, deque()
            for i, header_row in enumerate(headers):
                worksheet.write(i, 0, '', header_plain)
                for header in header_row:
                    while (carry and carry[0]['x'] == x):
                        cell = carry.popleft()
                        for i in range(nbr_measures):
                            worksheet.write(y, x + i, '', header_plain)
                        if cell['height'] > 1:
                            carry.append({'x': x, 'height': cell['height'] - 1})
                        x = x + nbr_measures
                    style = header_plain if 'expanded' in header else header_bold
                    for i in range(header['width']):
                        worksheet.write(y, x + i, header['title'] if i == 0 else '', style)
                    if header['height'] > 1:
                        carry.append({'x': x, 'height': header['height'] - 1})
                    x = x + header['width']
                while (carry and carry[0]['x'] == x):
                    cell = carry.popleft()
                    for i in range(nbr_measures):
                        worksheet.write(y, x + i, '', header_plain)
                    if cell['height'] > 1:
                        carry.append({'x': x, 'height': cell['height'] - 1})
                    x = x + nbr_measures
                x, y = 1, y + 1

            # Step 2: measure row
            if nbr_measures > 1:
                worksheet.write(y, 0, '', header_plain)
                for measure in jdata['measure_row']:
                    style = header_bold if measure['is_bold'] else header_plain
                    worksheet.write(y, x, measure['measure'], style)
                    x = x + 1
                y = y + 1

            # Step 3: writing data
            x = 0
            for row in jdata['rows']:
                worksheet.write(y, x, row['indent'] * '     ' + ustr(row['title']), header_plain)
                for cell in row['values']:
                    x = x + 1
                    if cell.get('is_bold', False):
                        worksheet.write(y, x, cell['value'], bold)
                    else:
                        worksheet.write(y, x, cell['value'])
                x, y = 0, y + 1
            today = date.today()
            a = str(today) + '.xls'

            response = request.make_response(None,
                                             headers=[('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel'),
                                                      ('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=%s' % a)],
                                             cookies={'fileToken': token})
            workbook.save(response.stream)
            return response
```

**This will print Today date name as excel  - 2020-03-18.xls**

Comment: thanks for sharing this answer you really save me, Thank you